# In virtualbox fullscreen mode, can I disable or move the popup menu bar?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running XP in virtualbox cause I need Photoshop and Illustrator. It works great on my 5 year old laptop which is stunning, but there's a minor annoyance when I go fullscreen.

The menu bar is in the bottom middle, and it pops up over the content. Since I use the escape buttons all the time I have no need for this to be there really, and it's really annoying when you try to change windows with the mouse and hit some random virtualbox menu item instead...

I know it's minor, and I can deal with the fact that you are probably just going to tell me to use alt+tab, but I'm just hoping there's some option I have overlooked that can turn off this bar or move it...

Thanks.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can disable the menu bar. For the setting to take effect you may have to exit and return to fullscreen/seemless mode. No need to shut down the virtual machine first.

Go to the settings of the machine. In "General" on the "Advanced" tab you can select: "Show in Fullscreen/Seamless" and there's an option to "Show At Top Of Screen".

[image]

In VirtualBox 5 the setting is under “User Interface” instead of “General”.

[image: VirtualBox 5]

Comment: Thanks! knew it must be somewhere. You have to shut down (not just stop) the machine to access the settings menu though.

Comment: As per tmbsteve's answer, you don't need to shut it down in the newer versions. Just go to Machine -> Settings and untick them. You can then use HostKey + Home (default host key is right-Ctrl) to bring up the context menu as and when you need it.

Comment: Tip: [Host key] + S  = settings menu. Very useful when you have no toolbar anymore.

Comment: Does anyone know where this option has moved to in version 5? It's not available anymore in my settings.

Comment: @richard I edited the answer to answer your question: it's under "User Interface" instead of "General".

Comment: Note: If the machine is running in seamless mode you need to leave and re-enter the seamless mode to make the changes effective (tested on VB 6.1.4).

Answer (score 17):

You can change the settings without shutting down the machine. Just go to machine > settings.

For the the menu bar settings to take effect, you will need to leave full screen mode and then re-enter it

Answer (score 9):

Following up on Andrew Ridout's screenshot through `Machine->settings`.
[image: Mini toolbar on the "User Interface" section]

Answer (score 7):

The option to display the mini menu at the top is now (I am running version 5) in the User Interface section rather than general.
I would post an image of the dialogue box - but I don't have 10 reputation points!

Comment: Hi Andrew, good to see that such an old question gets updated to deal with recent versions of a software! When you have gained enough reputation, come back and add a screenshot. +1

Comment: or you can always post a link ;-)

Comment: Where in the User Interface section is it?  It seems quite non-intuitive what all these options mean.