# Hide the taskbar in Virtualbox's Seamless Mode

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, taskbar

I just wanted to ask if there was a way to hide the taskbar when running VirtualBox in seamless mode. I only want it to run Photoshop and occasionally MS Office, I don't need the start bar getting in the way, taking up valuable screen real-estate.

I have set it to autohide, but that it can be a bit glitchy, for example, sometimes if I swap window the taskbar will then stay up until I go back to the Windows program and then leave again. That and it can be irritating when I just want to click on something near the bottom of the screen and it pops up.

Edit: I just had an idea as to how to the solve this but the site won't let me answer my own question with 8 hours of posing it, but here's the answer I came up with anyway.

> I realised I was going about it in the
>   wrong way; looking at the problem as
>   an Ubuntu problem or a VirtualBox
>   problem, then I realised it was really
>   a Windows problem, since you can't
>   remove the taskbar in Windows. Then I
>   had an idea. I found a program that
>   changes the delay for autohide so it's
>   so long that I never trigger it
>   accidentally.
>
> In case any one has the same problem,
>   the program is Taskbar Activate,
>   located here:
>   http://home.nordnet.fr/pmdevigne/TaskbarActivate.html.
>   It's not designed for the new Windows
>   OSes but with a bit of tweaking it
>   works. I unticked the “Get back the
>   bar in the background when it is no
>   more in use” under the "Activation"
>   tab in the setting dialogue and then
>   everything seemed to work.

Comment: Does this answer help any any way? http://askubuntu.com/questions/31798/in-virtualbox-fullscreen-mode-can-i-disable-or-move-the-popup-menu-bar

Comment: Ah thanks, that does actually. It doesn't solve the problem I asked about but it's one I had regardless.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards